# Aurelia-Router: Modify route params and address bar from VM with Router

Tags: aurelia

I want update the url-params in the address bar without routing.
But i'm not sure how to do this with Aurelia-router from a view-model.

In my case I send IDs in the url which gets picked up by the view-model's activate-method.

The route looks like this:
http://localhost:3000/#/test/products?0=2599037842&1=2599080552

Then I want to be able to remove IDs from the url **without reactivating the view-model**, url result exemple: 
http://localhost:3000/#/test/products?0=2599037842

Hopefully there is support for this in Aurelia-router

Thanks!
/Mike

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with `router.navigateToRoute()` method. `navigateToRoute` has additional parameters. Use `options` (third) parameter to modify how the navigation is done.

Example:

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';

@inject(Router)
export class Products {
    constructor(router) {
        this.router = router;
    }

    activate(params) {
        // TODO: Check your params here and do navigate according to values

        this.router.navigateToRoute(
            this.router.currentInstruction.config.name, // current route name
            { '0': params['0'] }, // route parameters object
            { trigger: false, replace: true } // options
        );
    }
}
```

From [documentation hub](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/router/1.0.2/class/Router):

> `navigateToRoute(route: string, params?: any, options?: any): boolean`
>
> Navigates to a new location corresponding to the route and params specified.
>
> Params
>
> - `route: string` - The name of the route to use when generating the navigation location.
> - `params?: any` - The route parameters to be used when populating the route pattern.
> - `options?: any` - The navigation options.

With `options` you control how the [history is updated](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/history/latest/interface/NavigationOptions).

- `trigger: false` - prevents the router navigation pipeline to be triggered
- `replace: true` - replaces the current URL in history with provided route (rewriting history), so it won't be triggered with browser back functionality

Comment: Works great - Thanks! One improvement that I found was to replace the 'products'-string with "this.router.currentInstruction.config.name" to get the current route-name programmatically. You could add this modification to your answer. :)

Comment: Great. Sure, that will work if you need to navigate to current route. Answer modified.

Comment: I found that currentInstruction was not the right route in my case (or have things changed?), but the passed in route as a parameter to the activate method worked instead. ie. activate(params, route, navInstruction)