# Enforce lowercase url's in Aurelia Router

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I'm working on an Aurelia CLI v0.32, RequireJS with TypeScript app. My application has several routes, some of which have parameters. The issue is that external referrers may redirect to UPPERCASED routes or parameters.

What I want is that all my routes - or better said: **the url's - to be displayed in lowercase**. For this, I'm willing to convert all `params` values as well, if this is required.

An example for a route definition, where `:company` and `:orderid` are strings:

```
{ route: ':company/:orderid', name: 'order-detail', moduleId: ... etc }
```

An actual request may be:

```
http://localhost:9000/ACME/ABC-123-42
```

Expected behaviour is that the browser url is lowercased to:

```
http://localhost:9000/acme/abc-123-42
```

Note: If you're familiar with C#/ASP.NET MVC you'll notice that I'm actually looking for the following behaviour:

```cs
services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
```

I'm unable to find anything related to this in the Aurelia docs, specifically [the RouterConfiguration](http://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration/). Digging around, I did found a way which feels a bit hacky. But maybe I'm on the right track here where I add a `PreActivateStep` to the routerconfig:

```js
private configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router): void {
    config.title = 'My LowerCaseUrl App';
    config.options.pushState = true;
    config.addPreActivateStep(EnforceLowerCaseUrls);
    config.map(Routes.maps());

    this.router = router;
}
```

And here is the implementation of the part that feels hacky:

```js
import { NavigationInstruction, Next, activationStrategy } from 'aurelia-router';

export class EnforceLowerCaseUrls {
    public async run(nav: NavigationInstruction, next: Next): Promise<any> {
        console.log('nav: ', nav);

        if (nav.params) {
            // lowercase the 'framgment' alone doesn't seem to be enough
            nav.fragment = nav.fragment.toLowerCase();

            // *replace* the params with all lowercase values
            this.convertAllPropertiesToLowerCase(nav.params);

            // the router has a navigateToRoute, which allows me to replace the url
            // inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39244796/aurelia-router-modify-route-params-and-address-bar-from-vm-with-router
            nav.router.navigateToRoute(
                nav.config.name,
                nav.params,
                { trigger: false, replace: true }
            );
        }
        return next();
    }

    private convertAllPropertiesToLowerCase(o: any) {
        // hacky attempt to convert the values of an object to lowercase
        Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {
            if (o[k])
                o[k] = o[k].toLowerCase();
        });
    }
}
```

Now it works partially. On the main route /companyid/ it works. But with more deeper routes, this breaks. I'm sure that with some work I can get this running. But before I dive into this further, my questions:

1. Assuming there is no native Aurelia way to configure this, is using a **PreActivateStep** the way to go to get the desired behaviour?
2. Is there a **particular property** on the `nav.*` I need to convert to lowercase?

Or am I completely going the wrong way here?
Thanks.

**UPDATE**: Matthew's answer seems to work!

Comment: It might be worth filing this as an issue on the router repo.

Comment: Nice question, this is something I'd like to think about making a core part of the Aurelia router. In the mean time, try my solution below. If you create a gist.run, I'd be happy to take a closer look, as the answer below is off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use Redirect in next.cancel

```
import { NavigationInstruction, Next, activationStrategy, Redirect } from 'aurelia-router';

export class EnforceLowerCaseUrls {
    public async run(nav: NavigationInstruction, next: Next): Promise<any> {
        if (/[A-Z]/.test(nav.fragment)) {
            return next.cancel(new Redirect(nav.fragment.toLowerCase()));
        } else {
            return next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Juliën if this works for you please accept and upvote this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Seems a lot simpler and cleaner this way, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work just yet. I will play around with it a bit further as well and update the question.

Comment: if you create a gist run i can iron out whatever isn't working

Comment: Totally my bad, Matthew: it does seem to work. I had to change the order of another authorizestep which was blocking in the way. Added a [gist as well](https://gist.run/?id=6d5acdef6106689c9df0f53a8f663177), but your answer is great. Thanks.